# Disable key pressing events when they repeat

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-events, 2d-games

Is there any way to disable key pressing events when they are repeating?

I'm developing a game and when I press a key, the players goes into running mode and goes back to standing mode when the key is released. The problem is that with repeating `keyPressEvent()` events, there are automatically `keyReleaseEvent()` events, making the player immediately going back to standing mode after going into running mode, thus resetting the step (that I use for the running animation).

What should I do to cancel this?

Comment: Since you are developing a game you probably have a game loop. Does it work to check every iteration if a key is pressed or not? I am not sure if autorelease/press is a OS functionality (i guess). Just log your key presses and releases in a set-like container (press -> add it, release -> delete it) and check every loop iteration if the key is in the container.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with Qt, I assume your are using Qt key events - in that case, use `QKeyEvent::isAutoRepeat()` to check if the key event is a "real" key event or an autorepeat event.

Comment: Thanks! it fixed my issue. I wanted to have a "hold" functionality for my keyboard events and it was not possible as in hold state, the pressed and released events were always triggered.

Comment: I can hide all autorepeat key presses but how do I know which autorepeat key release is the last?